# Reverse an image (stored in 2D array) vertically

Tags: java, arrays

I'm dealing with an image that is stored in a 2D array, but the image is upside down. What I'm trying to do is flip it vertically.  I need to swap the first row and the last row, the second row and the second to last row, and so on. Here is what I tried:

```
    public void mirror() {
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        int[] firstRow = imageData[i];
        int[] secondRow = imageData[height - 1 - i];
        int[] tempRow = firstRow;
        firstRow = secondRow;
        secondRow = tempRow;
        imageData[i] = secondRow;
        imageData[height - 1 - i] = firstRow;
```

This runs without any errors, but the picture doesn't change at all.

The height variable is the height of imageData[][] which is the 2D array where the picture is stored.

Answer (score 0):

You're swapping the rows *twice*.

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
```

Once `i` reaches values greater than `height / 2`, you start to access rows that have already been swapped, and swap them back to their original positions. To prevent this, the loop should stop in the middle, i.e. when `i` reaches `height / 2`.

You also have a slight logic error in your algorithm; you already assigned the value of `secondRow` to `firstRow` and vice versa, so those respective values are what should be the elements of `imageData[i]` and `imageData[height - 1 - i]`.

```
imageData[i] = firstRow;
imageData[height - 1 - i] = secondRow;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "swap" is a no-op.  Ignoring `secondRow` for a minute:

```
int[] firstRow = imageData[i];
int[] tempRow = firstRow;
secondRow = tempRow; // == firstRow
imageData[i] = secondRow; // == tempRow == firstRow !
```

and on top of that you're (not) doing the swaps twice over.

Instead, try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < height / 2; ++i) {
    int[] tempRow = imageData[i];
    imageData[i] = imageData[height - i - 1];
    imageData[height - i - 1] = tempRow;
}
```